# Freelancer Visa for EU especially German speaking countries

Tags: germany, netherlands, freelance, switzerland

I am an Engineer / PhD and have been freelancing as a consultant for a long time. It so happens that most of my clients are in EU mostly Germany, Switzerland, Netherlands.

I have been debating whether it makes sense to move to the EU. One of the German speaking countries would be a good option since I do speak the language.  What are my options to do this? Typically I am aware of Work Visas ( I myself held one for the US for a long time) but I don't exactly work for a company, I am a freelance consultant.

I do have a extensive history of travel to the EU for work as well (if it matters!). Any advice?

PS. I looked up the EU Blue Card site but one of the prerequisites is a "working contract with a gross salary of at least € 50.800." Now I make more than this amount but it's not really one work contract but just several separate consulting contracts with different clients and a mix of retainers, per hour billing, turnkey projects and contingent commissions.

Comment: I think "working contract" just means they want to see some documentation, and it would be ok to have several different contracts.

Comment: @TomasBy Thanks! I guess my question is whether "work" needs an employer versus a freelancer where it's more of payment for service without a long term employer employee relationship? I guess I'm more of an "independent contractor".